# Gnuplot - Map with discrete color scheme (maxcolors?)

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to plot a map with discrete color scheme and a textual color description.

But even though I set the maxcolors to 4, I get 6 colors. My options:

```
set title "Lit Map for Point X:5.0, Y:14.0 with Compactness: 61.45415361382562"
set terminal pngcairo size 1500,500
set output "img.png"
set autoscale fix
set size ratio -1
set cbrange [0:3]
set palette maxcolors 4
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "grey", 2 "black", 3 "blue")
set cbtics ("Free" 0,"Shadow" 1,"Environment" 2,"Placed Obstacle" 3)
plot '-' matrix with image
```

The outcome with maxcolors to 4 & the outcome with maxcolors to 3:

[image: outcome 4]
   [image: outcome 3]

What is wrong when I set maxcolors to 4?

Comment: Please include the actual data for this plot. How do you want your colorbox to look like? You have four colors but only three segments... What about something like `set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "white", 1 "grey", 2 "grey", 2 "black", 3 "black", 3 "blue", 4 "blue")` without setting maxcolors? Maybe you also need to set `set autoscale cbfix` (depends on your actual data).

Comment: In the best case it would look like this: http://i60.tinypic.com/sv5ssk.png - Link to the File with data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zlfp1ds53rxn634/testGnu.txt

Comment: What you suggested actually works fine, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values used in `set palette defined` are used only as relative values to determine the gradient. They do not correspond to the absolute values in your data.

I think your problem is that you have four colors, but only three segments. That seems to make problems with `maxcolors`. Independent of the `maxcolors` settings, you can define your palette as follows:

```
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "white", 1 "grey", 2 "grey", 2 "black", 3 "black", 3 "blue", 4 "blue")
test palette
```

gives you:

[image]

So, with a little tweaking of the `cbrange` and the `rmargin` and the following script

```
set title "Lit Map for Point X:77.0, Y:2.0 with Compactness: 53.70905606592658"
set terminal pngcairo size 1500,500
set output "pic.png"
set autoscale fix
set size ratio -1
set rmargin 10
set cbrange [-0.5:3.5]
set palette defined (0 "white", 1 "white", 1 "grey", 2 "grey", 2 "black", 3 "black", 3 "blue", 4 "blue")
set cbtics ("Free" 0, "Shadow" 1, "Environment" 2, "Placed Obstacle" 3)
plot '-' matrix with image notitle
```

you get the result (with 4.6.3):

[image]